# Firestore: "There was an unknown error while processing the request"

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

This is my query:

```
var timesRef = db.collection('times');
var timesWeek = timesRef
  .where('Date', '>=', this.mon)
  .where('Date', '<=', this.sun)
  .where('Task', '==', this.task)
  .where('User', '==', this.user);
timesWeek.get()
.then(function(querySnapshot) {
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    console.log(doc.data());
  });
})
.catch(function(error) {
  console.log('Error getting documents: ', error);
});
```

It yields this error:

> Error: The query requires an index. You can create it here:
>   https://console.firebase.google.com/project/myprojectlog-bd174/database/firestore/indexes?create_index=EgV0aW1lcxoICgRUYXNr...CGggKBERhdGUQAhoMCghfX25hbWVfXxAC

Problem is, when I click that link I arrive at a page with an error message in the middle: `"There was an unknown error while processing the request. Try again"`. Every single time.

Could there be a typical reason why this happens?

I know I can create a composite index manually but I wasn't able to do so successfully (I tried to create one with `Date: ascending`, `Task: ascending`, `User: ascending`, I'm getting the same error).

Just in case here's a [screenshot of the browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dGX9s.png).

Comment: What error do you get when you try to create composite index manually? When I open the links I get access denied (that is understandable) error in the console, are you sure you have sufficient permission to create an index?

Comment: Might be hitting the indexing limit. Try to reconstruct your query.
[firestore indexing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing)

Comment: @Dipen Shah: I don't get an error when I create composite index manually, it just doesn't change anything and I get the same error again. Socrates Tuas: unlikely, I just have 2 collections containing each a couple documents (it's a demo project, extremely small)

Comment: Can you check the logs and verify if your any of the security rules are preventing the request?

Comment: What log are you referring to?

Answer (score 4):

Verify that the project corresponds with your current account, or try logout / login with the corresponding account for that project.

Comment: I can't believe I lost so much time for some cache issue. I was logged with the right user, I logged out and in again, now it works... (this week I wasted hours because Chrome was holding some old code in cache and CTRL-R wasn't enough, I had to clear the cache in settings). Cache can be absolute evil for a developer. Anyway thanks!

Comment: @drake035, well I asked you to try incognito window 2 days before this answer, but you didn't ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think you are creating an index on a different project or you are using wrong project ID somewhere in your code. Your URL points to project myprojectlog-bd174, and in browser console screenshot it is timelog-bd174. Or you replaced manually when pasting here in question? :) Try opening that link from browser console in incognito window, you might have been logged in with wrong user on Firebase console or you have reached a limit for free plan.

Comment: "Or you replaced manually when pasting here in question?" < this :)